# Maintain variable value in method and caller method

Tags: c#, function, call

How can I maintain value of a variable in the calling function that I pass as parameter to call a function?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of closures :)

Comment: You can use byref, but it generally shows a weakness in the design of the code.

Comment: Is this for anonymous methods or standard method calls?

Comment: @Jeff means that though you _can_ do this, it is not a good idea. It is bad design and makes for brittle code (code that is difficult to change and adapt).

Comment: oh okay,so this is a way,but not recomended

Comment: Yes, precisely. If you're creating a function, it's expected it will return a result. Having passed in parameters mutated within this function is a "side-effect" and rarely classed as desirable behaviour. It has its uses but like habanero sauce should be used sparingly and not on birthday cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the ref keyword, this will persist your variable.

```
private void method()
{
    int a = 10;
    function(ref a);
}

private void function(ref int a)
{
    //do work and change value of a
}
```

Comment: upto you, whatever names you use in your program, or the number of parameters may vary